# JSON Serialization Returns Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

In our project we are taking values as json from services

Most probably my questions were asked many times but I could not find any solution.

Here is the code block:

```
  NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

  NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
  NSError *error = nil;

  NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

  NSString* userID = [jsonData objectForKey:@"user_ID"];
  NSLog(@"Success: %ld userID: %ld",(long)success, (long)userID);
```

Log:

Response code: 200

Response ==>

{"user_ID":4}

Success: 0 userID: 0

As you can see I want to convert json object to string but when I printout content of jsonData it returns null I guess I have an issue with JSONSerializaton. Can anyone suggest solution?

Thanks,
Umit

Comment: Check is `jsonData` is `nil`. If it is, log `error`.

Comment: I'm not convinced that jsonData is nil, try `NSLog( @"%@", jsonData );` to be sure.

Comment: unfortunately NSLog( @"JsonData: %@", jsonData ); 
returns JsonData: (null) @rmaddy

Comment: Ok, so what does `NSLog( @"%@", error );` say?

Comment: it says:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x165f8f10 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

@user3386109

Comment: The response string `{"user_ID":4}` is valid and should parse correctly. I wonder if there are non-printing characters in the response.  Try `NSLog( @"\"%@\"", responseData );` and see what you get.

Comment: @user3386109
I have checked it out, log says:
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"user_ID":4}</string>"

Comment: The response from the server is XML, not JSON. You either need to parse the XML to extract the JSON, or modify the request to the server to request a JSON formatted response. If you control the server software, then you can also modify the server software to produce JSON.

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna try suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test with the following code, it's OK. You should log the error and check the response data, it may contain some invalid encoding.

```
const char *jsonStr = "{\"user_ID\":4}\n";
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonStr length:strlen(jsonStr)];
NSError *error = NULL;
NSDictionary *jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSNumber *userIDObj = [jsonObj objectForKey:@"user_ID"];
NSInteger userID = [userIDObj integerValue];
NSLog(@"=========>User ID: %d", userID);
```